# Conditional Rendering in React Native unmounts component too fast and causes memory leak

Tags: react-native, fonts, memory-leaks, expo, conditional-rendering

I've built an Login System that checks if there's a token. If there isn't one, it renders the LoginPage component, otherwise, it renders the app itself.

```
    {
     state.token ?
     return (<LoginPage />)
     :
     return (<App />
    }
```

The logic for font loading is taken right out of Expo's documentation: https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/.

I'm using the useFonts hook.

The problem is, if the user is logged in, they are redirected to the main app before the useFonts hook updates the state but the LoginPage component gets rendered for a fraction of a second anyway, therefore it tries to modify the state after the component is unmounted. That throws the typical "Can't update the state in an unmounted Component. This is a no-op but it indicates a memory leak.."

I've fixed this by using the Font.loadAsync function in a custom hook I made and by checking if the LoginPage component is mounted before updating the state with the fonts.

However, I was wondering if there's a solution to my problem **involving the original useFonts hook.**

Is there anyway to let a hook modify the state ONLY if a component is loaded, if the behavior isn't baked in the hook itself?